# Simulating Touch Screen Events on Android

Tags: android, touch-event

Is it possible for a background process or softkeyboard to create touch events and send them to screen as if the screen was actually touched?

i.e. simulating touch screen events.

Comment: Are you looking to do this for testing purposes, or for actual production code?

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool that comes with the SDK called [Monkey](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html) which generates pseudo-random streams of user events such as:

- clicks
- touches
- gestures
- a number of system-level events.

You can use the Monkey to stress-test applications that you are developing, in a **random yet repeatable** manner.

There is also the [monkeyrunner tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) which provides an API for writing programs that control an Android device or emulator from outside of Android code. With monkeyrunner, you can write a **Python program** that installs an Android application or test package, runs it, sends keystrokes to it, takes screenshots of its user interface, and stores screenshots on the workstation.

Answer (score 2):

For button presses, you can use the following:

```
dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));

dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
```

A list of available keycodes can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

For touchscreen events, you can use:

```
 dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(
                    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, Xinput, Yinput, 0));
```